# What is the R*-Tree algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, spatial-index, r-tree

Where can I find enough documentation to implement an [R*-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R*_tree)?  Specifically, I need to be able to:

- Insert nodes
- Remove nodes
- Search for K nearest neighbours
- Find all nearest neighbours within distance x.

Is there a single place where this algorithm is clearly documented?  Or is there a clean, open source implementation I can study?  Even better, if you can point me to a javascript implementation then my work is already done.

Comment: Why is the [paper linked in the cited article](http://dbs.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/publications/myPapers/1990/BKSS90.pdf) insufficient for your needs? It contains a full algorithm description...

Comment: Found an R* Tree library on some website. https://github.com/imbcmdth/RTree/raw/master/src/rtree.js

Comment: @Mark E - The linked paper only describes one portion of the algorithm, relying on further citations for the remainder.  Furthermore, I would probably find it easier to grok code rather than an academic paper.

Comment: Awesome, who knew there was some else crazy enough to have done this already!

Comment: "r tree javascript" is a suggested result in Google.

Comment: That's fair, and you would've enhanced your question by providing that detail.  FWIW, Wikipedia also cites some C++ code samples; I'll go out on a limb and just expect that that code doesn't meet your cleanliness and documentation standards, or something -- but that information might've been useful, too.

Comment: Actually it is not an R*-Tree, but a regular R-tree.

Comment: The gaps are probably answered by the R-Tree, on which the R*-Tree extends by improving various methods such as the splitting strategy and overflow handling. Did you also check the Guttman article?